# Coverage test django logout

Tags: python, django, coverage.py, test-coverage

I got the django logout function inside my views.py :

```
def logout_view(request):

    logout(request) 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))
```

And im trying to test it using coverage with this code:

```
class TestLogout(TestCase):

   def test_logout(self):
        self.client = Client()
        response = self.client.get('/logout/')
```

But it's not working, my traceback returns none :

```
> /home/juanda/cost_control_repository/cost_control/cost_control_app/unitary_test/test_views_authentication.py(73)TestLogout()
-> def test_logout(self):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/juanda/cost_control_repository/cost_control/cost_control_app/unitary_test/test_views_authentication.py(73)TestLogout()->None
-> def test_logout(self):
```

This is the url for logout :

```
url(r'^logout/$', views_authentication.logout_view, name = "logout"),
```

I think function it's not beign called at all but i don't know what else to do...any help please ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show traceback without pdb and the full TestLogout class? Is there a user created in `setUp` method?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Mmm without pdb doesn't show any errors, coverage continues and finishes, but marks  logout_view as untested....that's TestLogout complete, got no more code there, and yes, i created a user in fixtures data but i dont know whatś going on.

Comment: Can you show urls.py regarding the logout and how it is matched to go to logout_view?

Comment: Of course , look :
url(r'^logout/$', views_authentication.logout_view, name = "logout"), updated in my question too.

Comment: can you print response.status  if response is not None, or use pdb break point inside logout_view? we need to be sure that this test is going to logout_view if not so the problem will be in `/logout/`

Comment: Sure, if i put a pdb inside logout_view it never breaks, meaning coverage doesn't even enter that function at all...the response gets none in the traceback i put on my question. In other words the test doesn't go there, dunno why =(

Comment: Is url working on the browser? If yes show me the full URL?

Comment: Yup, it all works perfect in the app and do just fine when i click "logout" href in the template ( <a class="tree" href="{% url 'cost_control_app:logout' %}" color="blue"> Logout</a> )...but not in the test with coverage. It takes me to login url after that  : http://localhost:8000/cost_control/login/

Comment: Try .get('/cost_control/logout/')

Comment: And show me the URL config for login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103498/discussion-between-jsanchezs-and-ahmed-hosny).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, It appears that there is a problem to the url. I think it should be

```
class TestLogout(TestCase):

   def test_logout(self):
        self.client = Client()
        response = self.client.get('/cost_control/logout/')
```

Also, I suggest to do login the user first. So,

```
class TestLogout(TestCase):

   def test_logout(self):
        self.client = Client()
        # Assuming there is a user exists in tests db
        # or make a user like.
        # User.objects.create_user(username='fred', email='test@test.com', password='secret') 
        self.client.login(username='fred', password='secret')
        response = self.client.get('/cost_control/logout/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

For running coverage, you can do:
`coverage run --source=.,cv_manage manage.py test`
where --source = [all apps]
this can also be configured in .coveragerc

Comment: That did it perfectly !! thanks a lot for all your help !!